# android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF

Tags: android

I am trying to detect Screen backlight On / Off.

I've found `android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF` related its event.

But I don't know how to use this.

Can you suggest me about how to detect screen backlight on / off ?

I missing some example or sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can have a look at [this class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html). The method  `isScreenOn()` might be what you need.

Comment: Hi, 
thanks for response.
Is there a permission to use this class ?

Comment: I don't think so, if it's not written in the documentation, i suppose not

Comment: Guys' isScreenOn this method is available on Android 2.1. 

I am searching this issue on android 1.5. 

Any suggestion ?

Thanks.

Comment: you could check the status of the brightness :     Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), "screen_brightness"); The value is between 0 and 255. I'm not sure it will work but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 5):

Create a `BroadCastReciever`, Add an Intent Filter including your Intent (`android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF`).

Just Override the `OnRecieve` function in the `BroadcastReciver` with your code.

Be Sure to include the `BroadcastReciever` in the Manifest File!

good luck! :)

Answer (score 5):

If you still need to use a BroadCastReceiver, you have to register it in code using the `registerReceiver(receiver, filter)` on one of your Activities.

The intents do not fire if you register them in the Manifest.

Comment: Did you mean that intent do not fire UNLESS you register them in the manifest?

Comment: @Peter, no he meant that a `BroadcastReciever` that has been registered in the manifest will not receive an `ACTION_SCREEN_ON`.  for whatever reason, google chooses not to expose that functionality through a manifest registered broadcast receiver