# Is it possible to listen for the screen dimming or going black while not in my app?

Tags: android, screen

I'm writing a Kiosk app that, along with having some UI elements, also has a service that sits around in the background while the user explores other features on the device, and wish to re-launch the UI portion of the kiosk when the user has walked away. I figured that the most reliable way to do this is to listen for the screen to go dim and react to that event. However, I'm not seeing anything in the documentation about a system wide broadcast that I can listen to that the screen state has changed. Curious if I'm just overlooking it, or if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this answer:

[android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377487/android-intent-action-screen-off)

FYI there is a full list of broadcast intents available in your `sdk/platforms/android-xx/data/broadcast_actions.txt` if you want to have a look. I found these two quickly, which led me to the answer I linked:

```
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
```

Comment: This answer is only applicable to SCREEN_OF (Display.STATE_OFF) not (Display.STATE_DOZE,
                        Display.STATE_ON_SUSPEND,
                        Display.STATE_DOZE_SUSPEND) This seems to be only available if certan settings are activated