# AlarmManager stopped when screen off

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am trying to develop android app; and I use `AlarmManager` to do something.

but AlarmManager stopped when screen off
and when screen on AlarmManager will work properly

how I solve this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377487/android-intent-action-screen-off

Answer (score 2):

The `AlarmManager` can use one the following four types when [setting an alarm](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)):

1. [ELAPSED_REALTIME](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#ELAPSED_REALTIME)
2. [ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP)
3. [RTC](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC)
4. [RTC_WAKEUP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC_WAKEUP)

When using options 1 or 3, the `AlarmManager` will not launch the `PendingIntent` if the device is asleep (screen is off + a few seconds).
Try using option 2 or 4 to send the scheduled `PendingIntent` even when the device is asleep.